# How to get woocommerce product collection in template file

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

I want to show Woocommerce products on my custom template page How can i get product collection in that page,Please kindly give some suggestions how do i proceed to complete it

thanks

Comment: What have you done?

Answer (score 2):

I found like this.
For More : https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/sample-products-loop/
https://www.philowen.co/blog/show-latest-woocommerce-products-in-your-template/

```
<?php
        $args = array(
            'post_type' => 'product',
            'posts_per_page' => 12
            );
        $loop = new WP_Query( $args );
        if ( $loop->have_posts() ) {
            while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();
                wc_get_template_part( 'content', 'product' );
            endwhile;
        } else {
            echo __( 'No products found' );
        }
        wp_reset_postdata();
    ?>
```

Just try it. i hope is useful

Answer (score 1):

You didn't provide much detail here, but you could also try to add them as a list:

```
<?php
$params = array('posts_per_page' => 5, 'post_type' => 'product');
$wc_query = new WP_Query($params);
?>
<ul>
     <?php if ($wc_query->have_posts()) : ?>
     <?php while ($wc_query->have_posts()) :
                $wc_query->the_post(); ?>
     <li>
          <h3>
               <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
               <?php the_title(); ?>
               </a>
          </h3>
          <?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>
          <?php the_excerpt(); ?>
     </li>
     <?php endwhile; ?>
     <?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
     <?php else:  ?>
     <li>
          <?php _e( 'No Products' ); ?>
     </li>
     <?php endif; ?>
</ul>
```

More details would allow us to help you more specifically.